# Why does my newly installed Django project only display the welcome page?

Tags: python, django, subdomain

Right up front: I'm pretty new to python and django, but I've done the tutorial and some other basic stuff on a local install.

I recently started a django project on a live server (hostgator.com, with fastcgi) to the point where it shows that "It worked! Congratulations on your first Django-powered page." message. Next, I uncommented the appropriate lines in urls.py in order to enable the built-in django admin. I also figured out how to restart the fastcgi on my server just in case.

Upon going to /admin, it still displayed the welcome page. In fact, no matter what I put after the /, it displays the welcome page no matter what. I have also tried creating a blog app and getting that to display, but that also didn't work.

I get the feeling I've missed something painfully obvious, or there's something horribly wrong with my setup.

It is worth mentioning that my django project is set up in a subdomain. Thinking this was the problem, I tried writing a middleware that overwrote process_request from a tutorial here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/. Still, the welcome page is the only thing that displays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

I guess it would help if I put up some code, which you think I would have thought before.

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^/$', 'blog.views.index'),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here are the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'blog',
)
```

I haven't added anything to any views.py just yet.

I have run syndb, and here is the list of the db tables:

```
auth_group
auth_group_permissions
auth_message
auth_permission
auth_user
auth_user_groups
auth_user_user_permissions
django_admin_log
django_content_type
django_session
django_site
```

Comment: Welcome, you need to put up some code; your urls.py, your views.py etc.

Comment: it's like asking a bunch of blind guys to check your code, we can't see anything!

Comment: you've probably got something in your urls.py that's matching everything. But hey, how can we tell?

Comment: Did you forget to run `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: I have run syncdb. I'll add the list of the tables to the question.

Comment: *I haven't added anything to views.py yet.*  Could be that Django's not resolving your root request then?

Comment: @ElfSternberg I would expect a 500 error in that case, not the welcome page.

Comment: @BrendanYoung Have you tried running your project locally? If so what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have restarted the server properly? Try putting some text in urls.py to provoke a syntax error to make sure the restart did in fact work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I accidently created a bug and delcared a url pattern in my main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = []
```

deleted it and used my own url patterns. And it worked. 
Happy coding :)